# Image is not sending to server php (myadmain) local host in android studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am sending an image to the server and every thing is good in android, (there is no error in logcat) the problem is that I don't see the image on the sever. 
The first time there was an error that the file is empty (in the bitmapfactory )but that error was resolved when I changed my SDK.

My android code:

```
public class fragmentA extends Fragment {


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private View rootView;
Button captureImg;
ImageView iv;
Bitmap photo;
Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
String picturePath;
private Uri fileUri;
Uri selectedImage;
String currentDateandTime;
String reading ;
String dats;
String theTestText;
private Button btnLogout;
private Button sendImage;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;
String ba1;
public static String URL = "http://192.168.1.2/android_login_api/reads.php";


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("FRAGMENT A", "onCreateView");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    captureImg = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button ok = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button send = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    sendImage = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }


    captureImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
           // if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
                }
        }
    });
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               upload();
        }
    });

    private void upload() {


    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // Upload image to server
    new uploadToServer().execute();
}







public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {



        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = iv.getWidth();
        int targetH = iv.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss");
        currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

}

public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return "Success";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.hide();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    picturePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + picturePath);
    return image;
}
```

that is the php code